# How to add a separate image from the game canvas in Java

Tags: java, image, canvas, interface

So I am faced with a situation that I have been stuck with for an hour.

Here's my situation: I want to add an image that says "Life:" separate from my game canvas very much like this game Legend of Zelda for the NES.

[image: Example]

Problem is: my code still only shows my game canvas.

```
public class Game extends Canvas {

           private Game(){

           JFrame container = new JFrame("Arcade Shooter Clone");

            panel = (JPanel)container.getContentPane();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            panel.add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ShipLifeTitle shipLifeTitle = new ShipLifeTitle();
            panel.add(shipLifeTitle,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
           }

    }

    public class ShipLifeTitle extends Sprite {

        private Image image;

        public ShipLifeTitle()
        {
            try
            {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Ship/shipLifeTitle.PNG"));


            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            g.drawImage(image, 200, 200, null);
        }


    }

    public class Sprite extends Component implements GameComponent {

        public Vector2D position;
        public Vector2D velocity;

        @Override
        public void update(long milliseconds) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `ShipLifeTitle` panel, you need to override its `getPreferredSize` method.

```
public class ShipLifeTitle extends Sprite {
    //...
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
    }
}
```

This will give `BorderLayout` some hints as to how you want the panel to be laied out

Comment: I did this based on your feedback but it did not allow that syntax instead I had to code it like this: public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null)); } Now the South region has a gray area and still no image is displayed. My ShipLifeTitle is a Sprite, not a panel.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, use to using `BufferedImages`

Comment: I assume that `Sprite` is calling `draw` from it's `paintComponent` method, you've left that part of the code out...

Comment: I am doing my own painting using a time-based technique. The Sprite Class is written that way I did not leave anything out.

Comment: So when you add it to a container, `draw` is no longer getting called...so you image can't be painted.  Since it's not on the canvas, you need to use Swing's painting engine.

Comment: Ah, you got a point there! I overlooked this. Thank you very much, MadProgrammer! =]

Comment: Yep, it's always the small things ;)